# "Length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent" when working with time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series distributed by years and quarters and I'm trying to see if I got outliers. I know the tso() function can help me but depending on the case, sometimes I got an error, a warning, or a correct result.

In every case I follow the same steps:

- I create the time series with ts():

`y<-ts(datos$Data ,star=c(2010,1),frequency = 4)`

- and then I compare the differences between the diff(y) values to determine the outliers:

`plot(scale(diff(y)),type="b")`

- Finally, I use the tso() function:

`tso(diff(y), types = "IO", tsmethod = c("auto.arima"))`

The only thing that changes in every case is the data.

The warning is:

```
"Warning message:
In locate.outliers.iloop(resid = resid, pars = pars, cval = cval,  :
  stopped when ‘maxit.iloop’ was reached"
```

And the error is:

```
"Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (ncol(xreg) == 1) nmxreg else paste(nmxreg,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent"
```

This is the time series with no errors:

```
Year    Quarter Data
2010    1   12.356529
2010    2   12.395149
2010    3   12.295765
2010    4   12.240107
2011    1   11.905208
2011    2   12.060915
2011    3   12.126025
2011    4   11.751741
2012    1   11.736685
2012    2   11.620524
2012    3   11.520704
2012    4   11.607289
2013    1   11.366788
2013    2   11.498101
2013    3   11.473295
2013    4   11.572743
2014    1   11.562924
2014    2   11.542621
2014    3   11.605167
2014    4   11.573911
2015    1   11.487357
2015    2   11.580524
2015    3   11.554012
2015    4   11.365059
2016    1   11.662779
2016    2   11.472675
```

This is the time series with the warning:

```
Year    Quarter Data
2010    1   12.098885
2010    2   12.251975
2010    3   12.278595
2010    4   12.198781
2011    1   12.18147
2011    2   12.146041
2011    3   12.180495
2011    4   12.383853
2012    1   11.932348
2012    2   11.931753
2012    3   12.084402
2012    4   12.01268
2013    1   11.961791
2013    2   11.99994
2013    3   12.021034
2013    4   12.017576
2014    1   11.93865
2014    2   11.992599
2014    3   11.807316
2014    4   11.793714
2015    1   11.805951
2015    2   11.769397
2015    3   11.936377
2015    4   11.547858
2016    1   11.731589
2016    2   11.699573
```

This is the time series that triggers the error:

```
Year    Quarter Data
2010    1   12.374566
2010    2   12.382634
2010    3   12.368434
2010    4   12.387004
2011    1   12.317263
2011    2   12.216698
2011    3   12.261756
2011    4   12.395845
2012    1   12.196844
2012    2   12.230608
2012    3   12.201484
2012    4   12.113136
2013    1   12.427369
2013    2   12.030637
2013    3   12.317837
2013    4   12.190659
2014    1   12.210278
2014    2   12.178031
2014    3   12.177677
2014    4   12.323287
2015    1   11.829239
2015    2   12.095647
2015    3   12.169596
2015    4   12.270401
2016    1   12.097291
```

Comment: None of the related question on the right is of help ?

Comment: No, none of the links on the right helped.